# how to submit ios build for distribution with NOTIFICATION SERVICE EXTENSION, i have to build two seprate build and submit them?

Tags: ios

how to submit ios build for distribution with NOTIFICATION SERVICE EXTENSION,  i have to build two seprate build and submit them?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/266-notification-service-extensions) it looks to be just another target in your project, like any other extension.

All extensions need a "container app" as their root target. My full app (your's needn't be one) included a photo editing extension (which is right next to yours' in Xcode). I needed to do this:

- Set up three targets: the app (a stand-alone app), a framework (shared code), and an extension (the photo editing app). **All in a single project, build, and archive submission.**
- In Xcode I gave each target a unique "Bundle ID". (You may only need two - I decided on one for my Framework target.) Typically you should choose something like:

  ```
  com.[company].[app] 
  com.[company].[app].extension
  ```

My submission was rejected the first time because I didn't have a second Bundle ID. I found enough online evidence to convince me that adding ".extension" would work. It seems some rejections happened with something else. (If I should ever add another extension I'll use ".extension2".)

The framework ID was **com.[company].kernel**, chosen arbitrarily.

- In the [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com) site "App IDs" (under Certificates, Identifiers, Profiles) are needed that corresponded to "Bundle IDs" created in Xcode. (For the most part, Bundle ID and App ID are the same - avoid thinking that a Bundle is a folder containing all files in your "app", as if you have things set up like me, your app contains all three targets.)